# Sharepoint - Exporting ListViewWebPart cannot be reused in Visual Studio due to ListId property

Tags: visual-studio, list, sharepoint, web-parts

Here is my issue:

On SharePoint, i create a CQWP/ListViewWebPart 'connected' to a list. Using importation of this WP to Visual Studio, i need to change the ListGuid dynamically because a list creation creates a new ListGuid in each deployment. Using Truez answer, i managed to make the CQWP work

```
 ContentByQueryWebPart cqwp = wp as ContentByQueryWebPart;
 cqwp.ListGuid = list.ID.ToString();
 mgr.SaveChanges(cqwp);

 <property name="ListGuid" type="string">2c3e1e58-4fca-4b0e-a982-ffe5ac770ae4</property>
```

But then for a ListViewWebPart, using the same idea throws me an error

```
XsltListViewWebPart xslt = wp as XsltListViewWebPart;
xslt.ListId = list.ID;
mgr.SaveChanges(xslt);

<property name="ListId" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">68296faf-1aac-40c0-8d35-42bd3e12ec3b</property>
```

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException -> List does not exist
( Using debugger the list isn't null and i do get it's ID in xslt.ListId = list.ID;

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before is add the web parts to the page using code and this gives you more flexibility in changing and updating the above properties.

The reason why I wrote this is because we were generating views dynamically in the list setup therefore we didn't have the ID's at that given time but the views existed!

Hope this helps

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Adds list view webpart dynaically to the page.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web">A Web object</param>
    /// <param name="filepath">The full URL of the page you want to add the web part to.param>
    /// <param name="listdisplayname">The display name of the list that the web part needs to reference</param>
    /// <param name="viewname">The display name of the view  the web part needs to look at.</param>
    /// <param name="xsllinkurl">The relative URL to the XLT file to apply.</param>
    /// <param name="zoneidname">The name of the zone to add the webpart to.</param>
    /// <param name="zoneIndex">The index to add the webpart.</param>
    private static void AddListViewWebPartToPage(SPWeb web, string filepath, string listdisplayname, string viewname, string xsllinkurl, string zoneidname, int zoneIndex)
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listdisplayname);

        SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(filepath, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

        XsltListViewWebPart wp = new XsltListViewWebPart();
        wp.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B");
        wp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
        wp.ViewGuid = list.Views[viewname].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
        wp.XslLink = xsllinkurl;
        wp.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;

        wpm.AddWebPart(wp, zoneidname, zoneIndex);

    }
```

I believe just by setting the list name to the ID will suffice using the above code.

Cheers
Truez

Comment: Thanks Truez for this answer. Regarding to it i created an Event Receiver that finds the list ID and i try to change it in the WebPart properties. One of my WP is a ContentQuery so using this code

Comment: Great I'm sure it could be easily modified to for the Content Query as well. Mark as answer if you found this useful!